# How to calculate the pressure a pipe can withstand?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, mechanical-failure

I was looking at high pressure pipes and their pressure ratings. I'd like to know how these pressure ratings are determined.

I assume that pipes are tested until failure, and the failure pressure is multiplied by some safety factor to determine its 'rated' pressure, but is there a formula to calculate what the failure pressure should be before testing it (based on the material, wall thickness, diameter, or other measurements of the pipe)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the ASME Process Piping Code (B31.3)

$$p = \frac{2 * t * S * E}{D - 2 * t * Y}$$

where

$p$ = internal pressure
$t$ = wall thickness
$S$ = material's tensile strength
$D$ = outer diameter
$Y$ = wall thickness coefficient (B31.3-1999, Table 304.1.1)
$E$ = material and pipe construction quality factor (B31.3-1999, Table A-1A)

Note that this equation does indeed have a safety factor included.

Comment: Note that 2tS is the force per length holding two halves of the pipe together, and (D - 2t) p is the force per length trying to separate those two halves. Y and E are correction factors to account for safety.

Answer (score 5):

In the world of plastic piping, the formula is different, because the material doesn't [yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(engineering)).  For [isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy#Materials_science) plastics, B31.3 shows piping as:

$$ p = \frac{2St}{D-t} $$

Where D, t and S remain the same as above.  However, the allowable strength (S) is given by an applicable ASTM specification, which functions the same as the yield stress - but is not always based on the materials ultimate strength.

Composite piping, being composed of [Orthotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_isotropy) laminates, doesn't have a well defined strength - the material is designed with the pipe.  In these cases, the original assumption that pipes are ***tested until failure*** is absolutely correct.  B31.3 states again:

$$ p = \frac{2SFt}{D-t} $$

Where a new factor, F is introduced.  S is obtained from the [Hydrostatic Design Basis](http://www.astm.org/Standards/D2992.htm) - and it is essentially an [S-N Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)#High-cycle_fatigue) for that particular sequence of lamination.  F allows conversion between the two tests - 0.5 for the static test, 1.0 for the dynamic test.

ASME is currently reviewing this method - and this is an exciting new area of development for them as they are generating a [new piping standard](http://gasapps.gastechnology.org/webroot/app/gtiishome/files/ASMEStandardsCommittee.pdf) to relieve the industry of the expensive and extensive HDB testing requirement.

Quality testing mandated by ASTM D2996 / ASTM D2992 ensures the piping is made the same way - any change in the formula requires a re-test.  Using this method, composite piping is typically designed for a 50 year life-cycle.